# Delphi: How to draw checkboxes on a FMX Stringgrid?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl

I tried to draw checkboxes on an FMX Stringgrid, but I have problems with
the DrawFrameControl, that needs a Canvas.Handle in the first parameter in
VCL, but in Firemonkey, there is no such.

I tried simply Stringgrid1.Canvas, but it won't compile.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: VCL and Firemonkey are kind of exclusive to each other...consider removing the vcl tag.

Comment: Why not using CheckColumn ?